# setText() no cambia el texto en los textView Fragments Android

Tags: android

Tengo un fragment que recibe un objeto y a partir de él rellena unos textView, pero en mi caso deja los textView vacíos. Ya he comprobado que el objeto se crea correctamente y devuelve información mediante un Log. Estos son los métodos onCrate y onCreateView, que son los métodos donde tengo código en el fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(getArguments() != null){
            Alumno alum = (Alumno) getArguments().getSerializable("User");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perfil, container, false);
        miTextViewPerfilDNI = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPerfilDNI);
        miTextViewPerfilNombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPerfilNombre);
        miTextViewPerfilApell = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPerfilApell);
        miTextViewPerfilNacim = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPerfilNacim);
        miTextViewPerfilArea = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPerfilNacim);
        miTextViewCursoCoordinadorUp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textPerfilCursoCoordinadorUp);
        miTextViewPerfilCursoCoordinador = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPerfilCursoCoordinador);
        miTextViewPerfilClave = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPerfilClave);
        miEditPerfilDato1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editPerfilDato1);
        miEditPerfilDato2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editPerfilDato2);
        miEditPerfilDato3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editPerfilDato3);
        miEditPerfilHobbie1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editPerfilHobbie1);
        miEditPerfilHobbie2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editPerfilHobbie2);
        miEditPerfilHobbie3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editPerfilHobbie3);
        miBotonGuardar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.botonGuardarPerfil);

        // Se rellenan los campos
        miTextViewPerfilDNI.setText(alum.getNombre());
        miTextViewPerfilNombre.setText(alum.getNombre());
        miTextViewPerfilApell.setText(alum.getApellidos());
        miTextViewPerfilNacim.setText(alum.getF_nacim().toString());
        miTextViewPerfilArea.setText(alum.getArea());
        miTextViewPerfilCursoCoordinador.setText(String.valueOf(alum.getCurso()));
        miTextViewPerfilClave.setText(alum.getClave());
        miEditPerfilDato1.setText(alum.getDatos_interesantes().getDato1());
        miEditPerfilDato2.setText(alum.getDatos_interesantes().getDato2());
        miEditPerfilDato3.setText(alum.getDatos_interesantes().getDato3());
        miEditPerfilHobbie1.setText(alum.getHobbies().getHobbie1());
        miEditPerfilHobbie2.setText(alum.getHobbies().getHobbie2());
        miEditPerfilHobbie3.setText(alum.getHobbies().getHobbie3());

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perfil, container, false);
    }
```

Si se precisa más información diganmelo por favor.

Comment: Si te fijas bien la variable `alum` la estas declarando localmente dentro del método `onCreate()`. Por lo que no puedes utilizarla fuera de ese método como lo estas haciendo en el método `onCreateView()`. Puedes agregar el código completo de tu **fragmento** y también, el de la clase **Alumno**.

Comment: @DavidMinaya y lo extraño es que no le da error de `NullPointerException`, por eso no lo tomé en cuenta en la respuesta. A menos que haya definido valores por default. Como no le daba errores me lo encontré extraño ahora que lo mencionas.

Comment: Puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió. Así no se queda abierta la pregunta. De igual forma, acostumbrate a hacerlo en tus demás preguntas si llegaste a la solución mediante la respuesta. Eso motiva a que te podamos seguir ayudando mas adelante. Buena suerte.

Comment: ¿Cómo se hace para aceptarla?

Comment: @PacoPepe Debajo del contador de la **respuesta** (donde aparece el numero con las flechitas para votar) hay una flecha de aceptación, le das click y listo. Intenta aceptar la respuesta que te ha llevado a la solucion, en las preguntas que haz hecho para que no se queden abiertas sin responder.

Comment: Vale, ya está. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas inflando una vista `nueva` de cero, en vez de retornar la creada en el return del `onCreateView`.

En tu caso, basta con retornar `view` que es donde se guarda la referencia modificada. Si ese no es el caso, asumiendo que no te da errores en runtime y dices que los "datos existen". Entonces revisa si en tu layout, el color del texto es igual al de tu `background`, suele pasar.

Como dice **@DavidMinaya** en el comentario, de igual forma tu objeto se está declarando de manera local al obtener el `Bundle`. Debes declarar `alum` como variable de la clase y removerle el tipo detras del nombre en el `onCreate`.

**RECOMENDACION:** para lograr mejor performance al pasar un objeto mediante un bundle, te recomiendo implementar parcelable en tu objeto, en vez de serializarlo.

Puedes ver una explicación de: [Parcelable vs Serializable](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/)

Comment: Vale, he cambiado el return para que devuelva el view y ahora me funciona, pero no sé si lo que devolvía antes era importante.

Comment: @PacoPepe No. Lo que devolvia antes ya lo estas devolviendo pero de manera modificada. Fijate que le asignas a la variable `view` el inflate. Lo que pasa es que dejaste el codigo tal cual te lo generó. Ese inflate es como quien dice tu vista, la modificas y la retornas. Antes retornabas solo la original y no la modificada. Si te sirvio la ayuda puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada y dejarme un voto. Saludos